# What is the appropriate way to update a large number of txt format data files in Git repository instead of using sourcetree staging files manually?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am just wondering there is any way that I can update a large number of .txt format data files to a git repository? In sourcetree, I have to stage every file by hand which is very painful.

I am also wondering if there are some ways that I can just provide a link of the files or something like in gradle so that I can just change the link and the git will update the files automatically instead of uploading all the files each time.

I need some guidance and directions of solving the problem. I know there must be several ways to solve the same problem but my purpose is not to bring any debates or conflicts. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `git add /` will add *all* changes to the index.

The `/` is a special [path specification](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html) that represents the root of the working tree in git. You can also use any path specification that your operating system supports (as long as it stays inside the working tree).

Comment: That is a good thing to know. Thank you!  Roland, I am also wondering is there any other way that I don't need to stage the original data files since there are 50 files and each of them is big. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: @Crystal I'm not sure what you mean here? If you want to save the files under revision control, you'll have to stage them. And since they're text files they will probably compress relatively well. You might want to have a look at [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/). Maybe that does what you are envisioning?